Looking for a design pattern similar to IDisposable (and Using)
I have a class that has a Start and an End method. I want to ensure that whenever a begin is called that the end must be called. For example:
var foo = new foo;
foo.Start();
...do other stuff
foo.End();

But I want to ensure that another developer cant call foo.Start without calling foo.End.
This would accomplish that but it requires the other developers to know to do it.
try
{
    foo.Start();
...do other stuff
}
finally
{
    foo.End();
}

I would love it to be similar to using where the dispose (or the end in this case) automatically call end when out of scope
using (foo.Start())
{
    //...do other stuff
}

Any Ideas or suggestions?
I've tried various patterns but can't get something I like and believe there must be something better.

So Start should create something that is IDisposable. That object would hold a reference to foo, and its Dispose would call End on that instance. Is that what you are after?

Create a disposable class that implements your start and end logic; with the Start stuff in the constructor and the End stuff in the Dispose method. Then, the pattern simply becomes using new StartEndClass();. I've used this pattern several times

Or Start itself should implement IDisposable. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

@Flydog57 it better be a struct than class. There is no compelling reason to allocate memory each time the Start is called.

There isn't a specific answer to what you are asking!  Decorator pattern is something you can consider. Which will allow for something to be called in the middle. Essentially you can use something to pipeline it. Honestly i can think quite a few solutions around implementing this. I would definitely use IDisposable as it is the simplest.

@TheodorZoulias The problem with a struct is that it gets a default constructor (that you can't change. You can also just declare an instance that sits in the method's stack frame and results in no code being executed

@Flydog57 having a cached IDisposable instance hanging around is reasonable, but I think that a struct is currently the standard way to implement the pattern. See the Lock.Scope for example.

Thank you guys, especially @Sweeper all are good input and got me what I was looking for. Please put as an answer so I can give some points.

@Flydog57 You can nest the struct inside the class that uses it and make the constructor private or internal.

As an alternative you could take a look what PostSharp offers for method decoration.

Thank you everyone.. with your input I came up with this
(consider this pseudo code, IDisposable is not complete, names are for the example not correct, etc..its paired down to the min)
public class MyStack
{
    public IDisposable Transaction()
    {
        return new UndoStackTransaction(this);
    }

    public void BeginCommit()
    {
    }

    public void EndCommit()
    {
    }

    public class UndoStackTransaction : IDisposable
    {
        private MyStack _myStack;

        public UndoStackTransaction(MyStack undoStack)
        {
            _myStack = undoStack;
            _myStack.BeginCommit();
        }

        ~UndoStackTransaction() => Dispose(false);

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _myStack.EndCommit();
        }
    }
}

Which allows me to do this....
   using (var transaction = stack.Transaction())
   {
       //Do Something
   }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Please pay attention to this: "One of the guidelines for finalization is that a Finalize method shouldn’t touch other objects. The reason for the guideline is to avoid touching objects that may have already been finalized. That’s because finalization is unordered." Quoted from Chris Brumme's Weblog.

Also please note that the convention for naming methods is to use verbs or verb phrases. The name Transaction is unconventional for a method. A better name could be BeginTransaction.

As others pointed out, you can implement IDisposable to get the behavior you were looking for.  However, there's a downside with this approach - the caller must remember to put it in a using block or call .Dispose().
You might consider instead to use a single method with an Action<T> delegate parameter:
public class MyStack
{
    public void WithTransaction(Action<Transaction> action)
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.BeginCommit();
        action(transaction);
        transaction.EndCommit();
    }
}

That way, the caller can't accidentally forget to dispose.
stack.WithTransaction((transaction) => {
    // Do something 
});

If you need to return something, make it a Func<T> instead.  If you need your method to be async, then use Action<Task<T>> or Func<Task<T>>.
FWIW, you'll find that many of the built-in APIs in .NET that were originally created with IDisposable have been deprecated in favor of this pattern.

It also gives you control of how to handle exceptions.  In the above case, if action throws, then EndCommit is not fired. If you wanted to ensure it was always called, then you could use a try/finally block.  You could even combine these approaches and make Transaction implement IDisposable, and put a using block inside WithTransaction.  Lots of choices are available, depending on your needs.

With the alternative using syntax introduced in C# 8, using becomes much easier to employ. That is, using var x = new something(); No enclosing block required. Dispose is called when the variable goes out of scope.

Upvote from me. I much prefer this 'higher order function' approach to the IDisposable one. As highlighted, it's possible to ignore but it's also misusing IDisposable.

I like this approach and it was my first thought but it has the drawback that I cant change local values which is happening often.  I am refactoring a WPF application and this is happening in the view model, and would require too many changes to be feasible.

The disposable works with using because that is how it has been designed in C#.
To make use of this feature in your Foo class, let it implement IDisposable
public class Foo: IDisposable
    {

        public Foo() {
         // Call start() in Constructor
         _Start()
        }

        private void _Start() {
         //Use a private method
        }
        private void _End() {
         //Use a private method
        }
        // Call end() when diposing
        public void Dispose() => _End();
    }

Use the above class as follows:
using (new Foo())
{
   // do other stuff
}


Thanks, sorry I wasn't clear, the main class is long lived. so I don't want it disposed, I want to ensure if one method (begin) is called, another method (end) is called

@Stetson Create a private disposable worker type in the main class. Do the Start work in the constructor, and the End work in the Dispose method. I can't really tell what your use case is, but the idea is that the disposable type is trivial; it exists only to run the Start/End work. How you integrate it into your code is up to you.

@Flydog57 that is what I ended up doing

MSDN: "Finalizers (historically referred to as destructors) are used to perform any necessary final clean-up when a class instance is being collected by the garbage collector...."
public class Foo
{
    private bool _ended = true;

    private void Start() 
    {
        if (!_ended)
            throw new Exception . . ..

         _ended = false;
        . . . . . . .  // some code here
    }
       
    private void End() 
    {
        if (_ended)
            return;

        . . . . . .  // some code here 
        _ended = true; 
    }
        
    ~Foo() // finalizer
    {
        End();
    }
}

This, while not going to keep developers completely honest, will keep application honest.
